# Access the word in the file with grep

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I have a conf file and I use `grep` to access the data in this file but not a very useful method for me.

How can I just get the main word by search-term?

I using:

```
grep "export:" /etc/VDdatas.conf
```

Print:

```
export: HelloWorld
```

I want: *(without "export: ")*

```
HelloWorld
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What does this have to do with SSH?

Comment: Because I using SSH command @Barmar

Comment: So? `grep` works the same with ssh or local terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GNU `grep` you can use PCRE and a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
grep -P -o '(?<=export:).*' /etc/VDdatas.conf
```

The `-o` option means to print only the part of the line that matches the regexp, and using a lookbehind for the `export:` prefix makes it not part of the match.

You can also use `sed` or `awk`

```
sed 's/export:/s/^export: //' /etc/VDdatas.conf
awk '/export:/ {print $2}' /etc/VDdatas.conf
```

Comment: The server does not answer. `root@sp1:~# grep -P -o "(?<=export: ).*" /etc/VDdatas.conf
root@sp1:~#`

Comment: Grep version : 2.27

Comment: It works for me with GNU grep 2.12, so it should work for you.

Comment: Is there a space after `:` in the file, like you show in the question?

Comment: Yes, there is a space. My fault. Right now I can access directly with your code. Thank you for your time

Comment: I want to ask you one last question. How can method be implemented without using `grep`, altermative?

Comment: you can use `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pipe the match to awk.

```
grep "export:" /etc/VDdatas.conf | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
```

This will print the second word in the output (after splitting the line on spaces).

Comment: The server does not answer. root@sp1:~# grep "export:" /etc/VDdatas.conf | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'   root@sp1:~#